# Adding redirect after the alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here a function that sends data in a form to Google Sheets. How can I execute the redirect button after the alert?

I have tried adding the window.location.href='', but it redirects the page without submitting the data.

```
<script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyXViROC5iq7PdxoCufOn5XfJTyArkmdQul_-pWwJ3Yc9GpwmZpO0WR2tkeVNUPA47u/exec'
    const form = document.forms['google-sheet']

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
        .then(response => alert("Salamat po sa pag fill-out! Paki-wait nalang po ang aming call..."))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
        document.getElementById("rider-form").reset();
        window.location.href='digitsorani.net';
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `window.location.href = xyz` line into the .then() branch of the promise.

```
...then(r => { alert(); reset_form(); navigate_away(); })
```

or, use an async event handler and wait for the fetch to complete:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   await fetch()...;
   resetFormAndNavigate();
})
```

Comment: ...then(r => { alert(); reset_form(); navigate_away(); })  worked for me thank you so much